# Fetching json array using Ajax Query

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, datatables

Request your help, on how to display a json array using datatables, below is the array type and the code which i tired, but nothing is displayed.

```
**JSON Array**
{"Server1":
  {
    "2020-01-29":3,
    "2020-01-28":0,
    "2020-01-27":0
 },
 "Server2":
 {"2020-01-29":3,
  "2020-01-28":0,
  "2020-01-27":0
 }
}
```

```
**Ajax Query**
$(document).ready(function(){
var table = $("#Srvtbl").DataTable({
            ajax: {
                    url: "getdata.php",
                    dataSrc: "",
                    method: "GET",
                    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true }
                  },
            columns: [
                        { data: "server[, ]" },
                        { data: "2020-01-29" },
                        { data: "2020-01-28" },
                        { data: "2020-01-27" }
                     ]
});
});
```

```
** Expected Output**
Server Name     2020-01-29    2020-01-28  2020-01-27
Server1              3             0           0
Server2              3             0           0
```

Comment: What is the current output you are getting back with this code?

Comment: The output is blank table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First this is not a JSON Array it's a nested Json object, an array have [ ]s

```
**JSON Array**
{"Server1":
  {
    "2020-01-29":3,
    "2020-01-28":0,
    "2020-01-27":0
 },
 "Server2":
 {"2020-01-29":3,
  "2020-01-28":0,
  "2020-01-27":0
 }
}
```

Second , *Server1*, *Server2* must be inline with the numeric values of each date

so your response data must be something like :

```
[
  {
    "Server_Name": "Server1",
    "2020-01-29": 3,
    "2020-01-28": 0,
    "2020-01-27": 0
  },
  {
    "Server_Name": "Server1",
    "2020-01-29": 3,
    "2020-01-28": 0,
    "2020-01-27": 0
  }
]
```

and columns :

```
columns: [
{ data: "Server_Name" },
{ data: "2020-01-29" },
{ data: "2020-01-28" },
{ data: "2020-01-27" }
]
```

please check = > [Data source types](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Data-source-types)